# on/off click events in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a click event on and off to prevent multiple function calls. Below is my code. The click is turning off but I can't seem to turn it on again. Thoughts?

```
$("#element").click(function(){
     doit();
     $(this).off('click');
 })

function doit(){

    do stuff...

    //turn click back on
    $("#element").on('click');

}
```

Comment: Put the `doit()` line after the `$(this).off` line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the handler back to the on method, also use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) as you want to fire it only once

```
function clickHandler() {
    doit();
}
$("#element").one('click', function () {})

function doit() {
    //do stuff...

    //turn click back on
    $("#element").one('click', clickHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arun! Worked Perf.

Comment: doesn't work. I have an element with an id="element", I have your code in a script block, jquery 3.3.1, nothing happens when I click the element.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have set the button off after calling doit() which turns it on. Try:

```
$("#element").click(function(){
     $(this).off('click');
     doit();
 })

function doit(){

    do stuff...

    //turn click back on
    $("#element").on('click');

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually have this in my file. Again, it turns off fine the issue is in turning the click event back on.

Comment: `$("#element").on('click');` doesn't turn anything on. You have to pass a function.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, I was just copying the questioner's code. Really, Arun has a better way of doing it anyway. Mine was sort of at a conceptually what's wrong with this picture and Arun's got more of a "what's the right way to do it" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `$("#element").on('click');` without providing the action handler is useless. You need to pass the handler again to turn it on.

```
$("#element").on('click', clickEvent);

function doit() {
    // do stuff...

    //turn click back on
    $("#element").on('click', clickEvent);
}

function clickEvent() {
    doit();
    $("#element").off('click');
}
```